# use flash animation as html background

Tags: html, flash

I want to make a webpage with flash background & want to put html contents on it. It is like instead of having any background color or background image i want animation that i have created in flash. Is it possible to make flash as an html background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can accomplish this. Just have look at this code & made setting according to your needs..

```
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:1;">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="put width" height="put height">
<param name="movie" value="put your swf file here" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<embed src="put your swf file here" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="put width" height="put width" wmode="opaque" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
</div>

<div style="position:relative; z-index:2">
<!-- Here you can add your html content -->
ABCD
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an [html object](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp) element and play the flash file through that.